# How to calculate the radius of the curved side of a triangle?

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles

In this image, only having these dimensions, is it possible to calculate the radius of the circle (of the arc of the line AB)?

[image: Triangle with curved side]

The centre of the circle is in the same X position as the line AC, but its Y position is unknown,

How can I do it? Sorry if it's a duplicate question, I could not find how to do this,

Comment: The arc is not well-defined. What is its centre? It can't be at $C$, because $AC\ne BC$. To put it another way: there are any different circular arcs that you could draw between $A$ and $B$. Which one do you mean?

Comment: There are infinitely many circles that contain $A$ and $B$. Three points define a circle. Need more info.

Comment: The centre of the circle is in the same X position as the line AC, but its Y position is unknown, can this help in some way or is it still impossible to find the radius?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X$ is the centre of the circle, and $r$ is its radius, then by Pythagoras in triangle $BCX$, $BX^2=r^2=(r-3)^2+4^2$.

So you just have to solve the equation
$$r^2=(r-3)^2+16$$

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way to calculate the radius. The construction is the same as Ethan's. In the figure below, $OM$ is the perpendicular bisector of $AB$, and $OA$ is the desired radius.

[image]

To find the length of $OA$, note that $\triangle AOM$ is similar to $\triangle ABC$, which is the famous 3-4-5 triangle. Now, $AM = \frac52$ , so $OA = $ ?

Answer (score 1):

Construct the perpendicular bisector $L$ of segment $AB$. The point at which $L$ meets the line containing $AC$ is the center of the circle you want.